# Certificado SSL wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seguridad, ssl

Buenos Días. Me gustaría aprender como configurar el certificado de seguridad, en Wordpress. Agradezco enormemente a quien desee enseñarme como se realiza este proceso.

Comment: No hay certificados de seguridad en wordpress. El certificado se instala a nivel de webserver (Apache, Nginx). En wordpress simplemente cambias la url del home de http a https (en el panel de administración)

Comment: Ok entiendo, pero lo que necesito saber es como se realiza este proceso, que ficheros debería modificar de ser necesario o que debería agregar

Comment: instala plugin CloudFlare Flexible SSL y Really Simple SSL, cambias la url a https y queda solucionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que he visto, ya tienes el certificado instalado y te falta sólo la parte de configuración del sitio, `<meme de squirtle> vamo a responder</meme de squirtle>`

**Estableciendo WordPress Admin SSL**

Necesitas modificar el archivo `wp-config.php` en la raíz de tu proyecto y agregas esta línea:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Ahora, para verificar, le das: https://[tusitioweb.com]/wp-admin y revisas si funciona con HTTPS.

En caso no te funcione, quita esa línea inmediatamente que hay algo que arreglar primero.

Si todo funciona, ve a iniciar sesión, y comprueba que tengas el candadito al costado del dominio en la barra de direcciones :D

**Plugin para SSL**

Ahora, vamos por el tema, los plugins y las llamadas al front-end que funcionen como se debe. Instalamos https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/ Esto te permite forzar a usar SSL para una página y ver los posibles errores (usando las DevTools de los navegadores, llamadas con F12) sin interrumpir a los usuarios.

La manera de usarlo es simple: cargas tu website, le das inspeccionar elemento y miras los errores de seguridad que te marquen.

**Finalmente, en el .htaccess**

```
# Force HTTPS RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Extraído de: https://www.shivarweb.com/7195/https-ssl-for-wordpress-guide/

Comment: Vale Fredyfx, que buena respuesta, muchas gracias por la ayuda fue muy oportuna.

Comment: de nada hermano, dale con todo el power 2.0! éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Comment: ¿Por qué recomiendas el uso de un plugin? Yo instalé un SSL en un sitio bajo WP sin necesidad de plugin, solamente poniendo en el `.htaccess` lo que acertadamente dices en la respuesta. Tampoco hice ninguna verificación previa con `define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);`, por el contrario, si verifiqué que la instalación del certificado era correcta con SSL Checker. [Aquí está explicado todo el procedimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177042/29967). En WP no es bueno tirar de un plugin para todo, al final tienes decenas de esos elementos que ralentizan el sitio, cuando no lo hacen inseguro...

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo primero que debes hacer es preguntarle al administrador de tu servidor(host) si dispone de ello y si es así, que lo active. Es posible que te de alguna indicación del estilo copia pega o nada, sin más. Después es sencillo activarlo mirando las opciones internas del panel de administrador de wordpress; es un botón.

Además si tienes bien enlazados los links internos de tu página, etc una vez lo tengas google no te dara problemas. En caso de tenerlo todo activado y en vez del candado verde te aparezca una exclamación hay herramientas online como http://nibbler.silktide.com/ que te pueden facilitar que ocurre.

saludos

Comment: Osea esto ya lo hice pero al activar la opción desde el panel de wordpress solo me queda como seguro el panel de administración, pero la pagina sigue sin ser segura

Comment: Como te digo, hay muchas razones por las que te pueda pasar eso y es que tengas links que no esten bien puestos y cosas asi. Usa herramientas como la web que te he pasado para evaluar tu web y ver donde estan los posibles problemas.