# He instalado un certificado SSL en mi sitio web, ¿qué debo hacer luego?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, seo

Tengo un sitio alojado en Bluehost (hosting compartido), y he instalado el certificado SSL gratuito que ellos ofrecen.

Ya el certificado está funcionando en el sitio, de hecho puedo acceder por `https://`, y el sitio ha pasado la verificación [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un sitio me indicaban que, para evitar problemas de SEO y demás, debo poner esto en mi `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Lo cual he hecho y efectivamente me redirige todo a `https://` aunque escriba algo como `http://www.example.com`.

Lo que quiero saber es si:

- **¿La configuración indicada más arriba es suficiente o tendría que hacer algo más?**
- **¿Debo poner eso en todas las carpetas de mi sitio, o sólo en la principal?**

Comment: va solo en la carpeta principal, si hay dominios parkeados o aliases a carpetas dentro de public_html (del dominio principal) revisar las reglas ahi también. phpcurl puede tener algún problema con el cambio pero son casos aislados y te los resuelven desde el servidor mediante ticket. 
verificar la carga de scripts en las páginas si alguno quedó cargando por http ya no puede ser insertado (borrarle el http: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con eso solo bastaria, cuando creas el .htaccess lo debes poner en la raiz del hosting junto con tu HTML. No necesitas ponerlo en tocas las carpetas.
Espero que haya sido de ayuda mi respuesta