# Como forzar todo el contenido de WordPress a SSL

Tags: wordpress

Recientemente estoy realizando una página web en WordPress y necesito que todo el contenido de la web se muestre por SSL, pero solo se aplica a la pagina principal, indicando que el navegador que se navega por HTTP en vez ed HTTPS.

Tengo instalado el plugin `SSL Insecure Content Fixer`, y tengo este código en el `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo pasé mi sitio Wordpress a SSL hace poco y lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

1. Fuera del bloque relativo a `# BEGIN WordPress`, **al inicio** de `.htaccess`

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```
2. Dentro del bloque `# BEGIN WordPress`, todo como habitualmente

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```

De ese modo mi sitio funciona sin problemas en `https`

Si hay algún otro problema, puede que sea debido al certificado. Puedes verificar que el mismo está bien instalado accediendo a [SSL Checker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) y poniendo la URL de tu sitio. Si no te valida todo, poniéndolo en verde ([como muestra la imagen en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177042/29967)), debes corregir lo que sea necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Si sólo cambiar el htaccess no te funciona, tal vez deberías seguir estos pasos.

1. Verificar que tu página carga correctamente en https://
2. Redirección de todas las páginas desde la configuración de wordpress, es decir **Opciones > General** y poner las dos urls con https como en la imagen:
   [image: Opciones a cambiar]
3. Si no quieres tocar el htaccess, hay un par de plugins que hacen la redirección y cambian contenidos inseguros: https://wordpress.org/plugins/https-redirection/ y https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/
4. Seguido tienes que verificar algunos parámetros más, por ejemplo **referencias en la plantilla** que puedan tener http:// (es decir, la configuración en Apariencia > Personalizar o en las Opciones del propio tema si tuviera.
5. En ocasiones, hay **referencias en las hojas de estilo** que contienen urls con http://, o **archivos accesorios** que pueden tener alguna llamada a http://, deberías localizarlas y arreglarlas.
6. Y por último deberías inspeccionar con tu explorador y ver si queda algún elemento inseguro.

Finalmente no olvides cambiar referencias de códigos de seguimiento u otros elementos que tengas. Además para no tener problemas, podrías poner las urls http://www. o https://www. de la siguiente manera //www. así cargarían http o https según el entorno.

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de lo dicho por los otros foreros, puede que te funcione si pones esto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://TUDOMINIO.ES/$1 [R,L]
```

Sustituyendo TUDOMINIO.ES por tu dominio real.

Ya nos dirás si funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo usando un plugin, WordPress HTTPS (SSL). Una vez lo instales, en su página de ajustes, puedes especificar si quieres asegurar todo el sitio o solamente la zona de administración. Para asegurar páginas o entradas concretas añade una caja al editor de WordPress en la que hacer que sea segura.

Si, por otro lado, prefieres asegurar entradas concretas con un código, puedes añadir el siguiente a tu plugin de funciones:

```
    //Forzar SSL en páginas y entradas
function force_ssl($force_ssl, $id = 0) {
$ssl_posts = array(22, 130, 573);

if(in_array($id, $ssl_posts)) {
$force_ssl = true;
}
return $force_ssl;
}
add_filter('force_ssl' , 'force_ssl', 1, 3);
```

Simplemente cambia la lista de IDs de las entradas/páginas a proteger en la línea 3.

Adicionalmente, puedes forzar seguridad mediante SSL en las pantallas de acceso y en la administración de WordPress añadiendo estas líneas al archivo wp-config.php:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

En la primera línea fuerzas SSL en las pantallas de acceso, en la segunda en toda la administración. Para desactivarlas cambia el parámetro “true” a “false“.

Y si quieres, también se puede forzar SSL desde .htaccess, para lo que tendrías que añadir estas líneas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://TUDOMINIO.ES/$1 [R,L]
```