# Redireccion HTTP A HTTPS con WWW no funciona

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https, letsencrypt

Estoy redirigiendo mi pagina de HTTP a HTTPS pero no funciona del todo,
mi pagina es de wordpress, y tengo certificado SSL de digital ocean con lets encrypt,
Estos son mis casos

```
FUNCIONA
http://mipagina.com -> https://mipagina.com

NO FUNCIONA
http://www.mipagina.com -> https://mipagina.com
```

este es mi .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.mipagina.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
</IfModule>
```

Muchas gracis por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como forzar todo el contenido de WordPress a SSL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/187254/como-forzar-todo-el-contenido-de-wordpress-a-ssl)

Comment: Probe con tu respuesta. sigue sin funcionar, pero gracias por la información

Comment: Tengo un sitio en Wordpress y con eso me funciona perfectamente. OJO, en el bloque por defecto relativo a Wordpress no hay que cambiar nada. Verifica también que la instalación SSL es correcta en algún sitio como SSL Checker. Y verifica que no sobre-escribes reglas en `.htaccess`

Comment: Tengo mi archivo .htaccess tal cual tu respuesta, verifique en SSL Checker y todo aparece correcto,  no sé que mas podría ser

Comment: por lo general letsencrypt en digital ocean usa certbot, el cual genera los archivos de configuración para cada dominio y/o subdominio incluido en el certificado, el orden de procesamiento de estos archivos de configuración puede hacer que tengas redirecciones circulares o que no funcionen como esperabas, si colisionan con las reglas del .htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas usando letsencrypt en digital ocean te conviene usar y editar la configuración default de [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-apache), esta utilidad te genera dos archivos `.conf` en `/etc/apache2/sites-available` por cada dominio/subdominio :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.midominio.com.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/www.midominio.com-le-ssl.conf
```

Si usas certbot para configurar sin el www vas a tener 2 mas:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/midominio.com.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/midominio.com-le-ssl.conf
```

En el primero ( que maneja las conexiones no SSL ) hay un bloque que redirecciona a SSL, se ve algo así:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =midominio.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

El truco está en cambiarle ahí el destino final:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =midominio.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.midominio.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

y lo mismo hacer en el archivo de configuración de ssl para el dominio sin www

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/midominio.com-le-ssl.conf
```

agregarle al final ( siempre dentro del bloque `VirtualHost` )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =midominio.com
RewriteRule ^ https://www.midominio.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

esto básicamente hace que las peticiones a "sin www" ya sean con o sin SSL vayan ambas a `https://www.midominio.com`

Ahora bien, puede haber una situación en la cual `midominio.com` empieze con una letra que está alfabeticamente posterior a la w, apache procesa los .conf en orden alfabético asi que tendras que ( previo apachectl stop y a2dissite para deshabilitarlos ) cambiarles los nombres a los archivos de configuración para que los tome en orden y evitar redirecciones extra o en el peor de los casos redirecciones circulares, quedando mas o menos así:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/001-midominio.com.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/001-midominio.com-le-ssl.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/002-www.midominio.com.conf
/etc/apache2/sites-available/002-www.midominio.com-le-ssl.conf
```

Con esto te evitas tocar el `.htaccess` y wordpress siempre verá las peticiones a  `https://www.midominio.com`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con:

```
  # Redireccionar de HTTP a HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:/www.ejemplo.es/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Seria fuera del bloque de wordpress?

Comment: ¿Por qué se tiene que hacer esto?