# ¿Como forzar https en mi página con ubuntu?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, ssl, https

En mi pagina ya tengo el certificado SSL pero el problema es que se puede quitar el https de a url de manera manual haciendo la página insegura. ¿Como puedo forzar a que siempre tenga el https si mi servidor es ubuntu?

Comment: Usa `.htaccess`, [este artículo (en inglés)](https://linuxize.com/post/htaccess-force-https/) tiene más información al respecto.

Comment: Tenemos el .htaccess pero el de la ruta raiz choca con los que se encuentran en otras carpetas

Comment: ¿Tienes algún panel de control para tu sitio? (Ya sea cPanel, que tu página esté en CloudFlare o un panel de control personalizado del tu hosting). Lo digo por que, en general, los paneles de control para los sitios web ofrecen la opción _forzar HTTPS_ en la sección de seguridad.

Comment: la mas sencilla es cerrar el puerto 80 y sólo dejar la def del 443 en el serverconf, si hay varios dominios o varios server.conf fijate de cambiar los nombres para que los tome en orden https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/393869/81450

Answer (score 0):

.htacces debe estar en la raiz de tu proyecto.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

si te refieres al de la ruta raiz, podes cambiar el virtualhost en el puerto 80 y forzarlo al https, ej:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName midominio.com
ServerAlias www.midominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/midominio.com/public_html

<Directory /var/www/midominio.com/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =midominio.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=permanent]
```

Comment: Lo intente y no cambio nada. Profundizando mas encontre mas htaccess dentro de otras rutas