Problemas con virtual host - apache2 - Debian
Estoy configurando un servidor web en apache2 para que soporte múltiples paginas, se me ocurre configurar los sitios con virtual host, pero no consigo que funcione, a continuación muestro las configuraciones actuales.

Los permisos ya están bien, por que tengo configurados usuarios ftp, en cada carpeta y pueden ingresar enjaulados a sus carpetas, pero en este caso especial, lo que necesito es abrir el index.php de la carpeta wordpress que se encuentra en "sitiocuatro"
asi que quise hacerlo con virtualhost de la siguiente manera.
root@httpds:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# ls
000-default.conf  sitiocuatro.com.conf
root@httpds:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# tail -50 sitiocuatro.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitio.com
    ServerName sitiocuatro.com
    ServerAlias www.sitiocuatro.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sitiocuatro/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitiocuatro.com_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitiocuatro.com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
root@httpds:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled#

Se habilito el sitio.
a2ensite sitiocuatro.com.conf
systemctl reload apache2

pretendo abrir en mi navegador algo así www.sitiocuatro.com/wordpress/index.php, pero no funciona, imagino que es por que el dominio lo esta buscando en mis dns públicos, así que tendría que instalar un dns local para eso.
así que lo estoy haciendo así, 192.168.6.22/wordpress/index.php, pero el servidor dice que no encuentra la url.

Que me estará haciendo falta? que me aconsejan?
Cordial saludo

1/ <VirtualHost *:80> + ServerName sitiocuatro.com  significa que una petición en el puerto 80 que pida el dominio sitiocuatro.com será servida desde la carpeta DocumentRoot /var/www/sitiocuatro/public no hay mas que eso. si el navegador no resuelve el dominio, no lo va a encontrar. poniendo la ip tampoco lo va a encontrar si la config del 000-default.conf apunta a otro document root.  si ajustas el default para que vaya a la carpeta correcta, ahi wordpress te va a protestar pq la ip no es el domino ( o que el dominio no es la ip  )

2/ según el sistema operativo que tengas o incluso el tipo de router que tengas, direccionar un dominio a una "ip local" puede ser tan sencillo como editar un archivo de texto ( generalmente /etc/hosts o %windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ) y flushear dns . lo que se estila es usar un dominio .local o .test

3/ el orden en que se procesan los archivos de configurcion es alfabetico así que el 000-default.conf toma precedencia. (  ver ejemplos en  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/393869/81450 )

Gracias compañero, tenes toda la razon, el error era con el dominio, lo resolvere con un servidor dns local, interesante la opcion que das para resolverlo, muchas gracias.

El problema parece estar relacionado con la configuración de DocumentRoot en el archivo de configuración del VirtualHost. Como estás tratando de acceder a www.sitiocuatro.com/wordpress/index.php, deberías ajustar la configuración de DocumentRoot para apuntar a la carpeta correcta que contiene WordPress.
Solución: Cambia la línea DocumentRoot /var/www/sitiocuatro/public a:
DocumentRoot /var/www/sitiocuatro/public/wordpress

Luego, recarga Apache:
systemctl reload apache2


gracias por su ayuda, he realizado el cambio propuesto, pero sigo igual, estoy tratando de mirar si hay algo que hacer en el htacces. 

ya encontre el problema, lo que ocurre es que www.sitiocuatro.com en virtual host se toma como dominio, obviamente no hay un servidor dns quien resuelva ese dominio, asi que la solucion por ahora fue poner la ip directamente del servidor.

Instalare un servidor dns para que resuelva ese dominio localmente, así lo podría usar como lo tenia antes en virtual host, con el dominio.
Gracias stina, tu aporte me ayudo a realizar nuevas pruebas.
