# Instalar certificado SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, certificado-ssl, openssl

Tengo que instalar un certificado Standard SSL en una página en donde la dirección es la siguiente home.mi_dominio.cl y al momento de generar mi CRS, no sé si debo poner en el nombre común home.mi_dominio.cl o www.mi_dominio.cl.

Comment: Ponte en contacto con soporte con la entidad con la que estas emitiendo el certificado, por cierto, me imagino que el certificado es de tipo Wildcard SSL.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa tenemos solamente el certificado estandar. Gracias por la respuesta, ahora entiendo porque no me funcionaba nada de lo que hacia.

Comment: El nombre que pongas en el certificado debe ser exactamente el mismo que se utilizará para la raíz del sitio web. Ej. www.misitio.com.
Ese certificado será válido para cualquier www.misitio.com/miruta , pero no será válido para otro site, por ejemplo sit2.misitio.com.

Comment: Supongo que tendrás instalado el certificado correctamente en tu dominio principal y en el subdominio. Yo lo hice poniendo esto en los archivos `.htaccess` del directorio raíz de cada uno: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` . También hay que verificar con alguna herramienta que el certificado funciona correctamente. [En esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177042/29967) expliqué el procedimiento que seguí en mi caso y todo me funciona a la perfección.