# Problemas de ssl en las paginas internas

Tags: ssl, certificado-ssl

Le instale un certificado ssl a una pagina web, y funciona en la pagina principal, pero cuando navego a las internas ya no tiene el ssl.

https://abogadosasejuridicas.com/
http://abogadosasejuridicas.com/areas/derecho-civil

A que se debe?

Comment: Intenta poner esto en el archivo `.htaccess` del directorio público, llamado generalmente `public_html`.... **`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`**  Luego, asegúrate de que el certificado está bien instalado y funcionando mediante algún checker. [En esta pregunta comparto mi procedimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/177042/29967)  al instalar mi SSL y todo me funciona sin problemas. Hay una dirección de un checker también.

Comment: El segundo link no es https, por eso no tiene ssl. Lo que comenta @A.Cedano debiera redirigir cualquier url http a la misma con https.

Answer (score 1):

Por Pedido de otro usuario voy a editar y completar esta respuesta:
Tienes un WP, 
-Crear una cuenta en cloudflare: Esta trae un certificado SSL genérico gratuito y te brinda seguridad contra ataques.
-Para esto debes cambiar los DNS de dominio. (No te preocupes la web no se cae, ni te darás cuenta del cambio)
-Para evitar un error común de Cloudflare con algunos servidores, instala el Plugin CloudFlare Flexible SSL.
-Luego ya pasado el periodo de 24 horas ( a veces es casi inmediata la activación del Certificado SSL) instala el plugin Really Simple SSL, el cual funciona solo si tienes un certificado valido, en este caso el de Cloudflare.
-Debes cambiar la URL de wordpress de http a https, el mismo plugin te lo pide hacer.
-Por último si tienes contenidos mixtos(de varias fuentes no solo de tu servidor local) configura el Certificado SSL como "Flexible"
-En la sección de "page rules" reglas de cloudflare añades lo siguiente:
http://"asterisco"tusitioweb.com/"asterisco" always use HTTPS
-Ya queda todo con SSL.
Espero te sirva para tus sitios web en WP.
Nota: Coloque la palabra "asterisco" porque no muestra el símbolo asterisco en la edición.

Comment: como sabes que tiene WP?

Comment: Click derecho, ver código fuente de la página. :)

Comment: ¿Solución sencilla? Estás recomendando que instale ¡dos plugin! Será que yo soporto cada vez menos los plugin... Cada plugin es carga extra para el sitio y menos seguridad. Si el OP tiene un hosting decente, le ofrecerá un certificado SSL gratuito, el cual se instala activándolo en cPanel y luego poniendo lo que comento más arriba en la pregunta. Es una solución sencilla, usamos algo por lo que pagamos (porque el hosting es de pago claro) y nos evitamos instalar ¡dos plugin para tener un certificaso SSL! (eso es lo peor, dos plugin para eso OMG).